# find text in file starting from nth line onwards, using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to search for a keyword in a file, starting from the nth line onwards.
And if its found, set a variable to true
For example, file contents of testtext.txt:

```
abc-0
def-0
xyz-0
abc-1
xxx-1
```

I want to search keyword 'def' from the 3rd line onwards and if found, print true.
Also assuming the nth line is a pass in value.

I have a rough idea below, but not sure how to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

keyword=def
nthline=3
flag=false

count=$(awk 'NR>$nthline' ./testtext.txt | grep '$keyword' | wc -l)
if [[ $count -gt 0 ]];then
  flag=true
fi

echo $flag
```

Expected output should be false, because def doesnt exist on the 3rd line onwards.

Problem is I cannot pass in the 'nthline' variable into the NR> of awk
and also cannot pass in $keyword to the grep on that line

I have tested using actual values instead of pass in, it works, so the commands should be working.

```
count=$(awk 'NR>3' ./testtext.txt | grep 'def' | wc -l)
```

Is there any way to do this, or any other better solution?

EDIT:
Got a solution that is almost 90% there, but I need to assign the variable after the flag is true. this is what I have so far, I am not sure if there is any better way of doing it.

```
#!/bin/bash

flagz=false
tgt="def"
n=$1

flagz=$(awk -v tgt="$tgt" -v n="$n" flag="$flagz"'
FNR>=n && index($0,tgt){
    print("true1")
    exit
}
' ./testtext.txt)

echo "$flagz"
```

Comment: Research difference between single and double quotes. Resaerch how to use variables in AWK

Comment: Something like `tail .... | grep ....`. With `tail`, you remove the first n lines, and `grep` searches the pattern in the remaining ones. The alternative would be an `awk` solution, but then you don't need `grep` anymore. It also depends on the complexity of the search pattern. For instance, `grep` allows (via the `-P` option) _PCRE_ patterns, which you don't have in `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to do this entirely in `awk` since you are already using awk to slice the file.

Example:

```
tgt="def"
n=3

awk -v tgt="$tgt" -v n="$n" '
BEGIN{flag="false"}
FNR>=n && index($0,tgt){
    flag="true"
    exit
}
END{print flag}' file
```

Alternatively, you can make a pipe and then inspect `$?` to see if `grep` found your match:

```
tgt="def"
n=2

tail -n "+$n" file | grep "$tgt" >/dev/null
```

Now `$?` will be `0` if the grep finds the pattern and `1` if it is not found. Then you can set a flag like so:

```
flag="false"
tail -n "+$n" file | grep "$tgt" >/dev/null 
[ $? ] && flag="true"
```

Now `flag` is set true / false based on the grep. The command `tail -n +[some number] file` will print the file contents from the absolute line number onward.

For large files, the awk is significantly more efficient since it exits on the first match.

---

**Edit based on update.**

The issue is setting a Bash flag to `true` or `false` based on a process.

The `$?` [Special Parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) is set based on the *exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.* So pick your method to slice the file and detect the string and then set the flag in your script based on `$?` immediately after the pipe. Be aware that *testing* `$?` resets `$?` before it is tested -- so you either need to capture the value of `$?` before the test or use it in the pipeline itself.

These methods work:

**1) Capture $? and test:**

```
awk -v tgt="$tgt" -v n="$n" -v flag=1 '
FNR>=n && index($0,tgt){
    flag=0
    exit
}
END{ exit flag }
' ./testtext.txt 
res=$?
[ $res -eq 1 ] && flagz=false || flagz=true
```

**2) Capture a string result and test that:**

```
res=$(awk -v tgt="$tgt" -v n="$n" -v flag="false" '
FNR>=n && index($0,tgt) {
    flag="true"
    exit
}
END{ print flag }' ./testtext.txt)

[ $res = "false" ] && flagz=false || flagz=true
```

**3) Use a pipe and test in the pipe:**

```
tail -n "+$n" file | grep "$tgt" >/dev/null && flagz=true || flagz=false
```

My preference is **3** for small files and **2** for big files.

Comment: You can replace `>/dev/null` redirection by grep `-q` option.

Comment: Thanks, this works but is 90% of the way there, I need one last step to assign the 'flag' variable to a value outside awk, as I plan to use the flag in other parts of the script. I edited my question for the new code I have, not sure if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: You can use awk exit values and set the shell flag similarly to the last solution there.

Comment: @mouviciel: Yes, true but then you hide errors from grep. `>/dev/null` hides normal output but prints errors normally.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with `sed` and a range expression telling `sed` to search from line 3 to end `3,$`. The types of expressions that accept `addr1,addr2` is limited but does include the traditional substitute form of `sed 's/find/replace/`. Where you can search for the entire line containing `def` and then replace it with `&` (shorthand for the entire matched expression).

To control printing pass the `-n` option (suppress normal printing of pattern space) and add `p` (print) at the end of the substitute expression, e.g.

```sh
sed -n '3,$ s/^.*def.*$/&/p' file
```

The above skips the first two lines and begins the search/replacement on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting:

```
awk 'NR > 3 && /def/{print 1}' testtext.txt
```

`NR > 3` means if the total number of records greater than 3 `&&` the query `def` in `/def` was found, `print 1`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `RS="$^"` when the default record separator of `'\n'` would behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tail -n "+$nthline" testtext.txt | grep -qF -- "$keyword" && flag=true || flag=false
```